# I made Rational class using BigInteger but displays nothing

Tags: java

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int T = sc.nextInt();

        for (int t = 0; t < T; t++) {
            Rational r1 = new Rational(new BigInteger(sc.next()), new BigInteger(sc.next()));
            Rational r2 = new Rational(new BigInteger(sc.next()), new BigInteger(sc.next()));

            System.out.println(r1 + " + " + r2 + " = " + r1.add(r2));
            System.out.println(r1 + " - " + r2 + " = " + r1.subtract(r2));
            System.out.println(r1 + " * " + r2 + " = " + r1.multiply(r2));
            System.out.println(r1 + " / " + r2 + " = " + r1.divide(r2));
        }
    }
}

class Rational extends Number implements Comparable<Rational> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BigInteger numerator = BigInteger.ZERO;
    private BigInteger denominator = BigInteger.ONE;

    public Rational() {
        this(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    // set numerator and denominator
    public Rational(BigInteger numerator, BigInteger denominator) {
        BigInteger gcd = gcd(numerator, denominator);
        this.numerator = ((denominator.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0) ? new BigInteger("1") : new BigInteger("-1"))
            .multiply(numerator.divide(gcd));
        this.denominator = denominator.abs().divide(gcd);
    }
    // Find GCD of two BigIntegers
    private static BigInteger gcd(BigInteger n, BigInteger d) {
        BigInteger n1 = n.abs();
        BigInteger n2 = d.abs();
        BigInteger gcd = BigInteger.ONE;

        for (BigInteger k = BigInteger.ONE; k.compareTo(n1) <= 0 && k.compareTo(n2) <= 0; k.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            if (n1.mod(k).equals(BigInteger.ZERO) && n2.mod(k).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
                gcd = k;
        }
        return gcd;
    }

    public BigInteger getNumerator() {
        return numerator;
    }

    public BigInteger getDenominator() {
        return denominator;
    }

    public Rational add(Rational secondRational) {
        BigInteger n = (numerator.multiply(secondRational.getDenominator()))
            .add(denominator.multiply(secondRational.getNumerator()));
        BigInteger d = denominator.multiply(secondRational.getDenominator());
        return new Rational(n, d);
    }

    public Rational subtract(Rational secondRational) {
        BigInteger n = (numerator.multiply(secondRational.getDenominator()))
            .subtract(denominator.multiply(secondRational.getNumerator()));
        BigInteger d = denominator.multiply(secondRational.getDenominator());
        return new Rational(n, d);
    }

    public Rational multiply(Rational secondRational) {
        BigInteger n = numerator.multiply(secondRational.getNumerator());
        BigInteger d = denominator.multiply(secondRational.getDenominator());
        return new Rational(n, d);
    }

    public Rational divide(Rational secondRational) {
        BigInteger n = numerator.multiply(secondRational.getDenominator());
        BigInteger d = denominator.multiply(secondRational.numerator);
        return new Rational(n, d);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (denominator.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 0)
            return numerator + "";
        else
            return numerator + "/" + denominator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if ((this.subtract((Rational) (other))).getNumerator().equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int intValue() {
        return (int) doubleValue();
    }

    @Override
    public float floatValue() {
        return (float) doubleValue();
    }

    @Override
    public double doubleValue() {
        double x = this.getNumerator().doubleValue();
        double y = this.getDenominator().doubleValue();
        return x / y;
    }

    @Override
    public long longValue() {
        return (long) doubleValue();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Rational o) {
        if (this.subtract(o).getNumerator().compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0)
            return 1;
        else if (this.subtract(o).getNumerator().compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Hello, I'm studying java.
I tried to use BigInteger in Rational class.
I searched Internet and modified many parts of the code but still not working.

If I write input on console, the program displays nothing and does not terminate.

What is the problem in my code?
I'm really stressed:( Plz help me!

Comment: Thanks. Oh now program works but Time Limit Exceed.....;(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BigInteger` is immutable. You cannot do `k.add(BigInteger.ONE)` and expect `k` to change. You have to do `k = k.add(BigInteger.ONE)`.

You do this in your `gcd` method which is called during construction so the first time you create a `Rational` `gcd` goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: @girlcrush Please mark this question as solved by clicking on the checkmark icon next to this answer. Thank you.